# How to run cucumber and jasmine tests sequentually

Tags: jasmine, cucumber, protractor, cucumberjs

I need to have **(I have to, it's not my decision and I cannot alter it)** test-sets in both jasmine and cucumber. So I've made two folders with specs and two conf.js files, one for each framework.

When I need to run both jasmine and cucumber tests, I need to run protractor with one config and then run it again with another config.

So the question is: is there any way to make protractor run jasmine and cucumber tests consequently (e.g. first run all jasmine tests, then run all cucumber tests) in "one click"?

If you need any details about environment: I'm currently running tests in IDEA, and later there will be a Jenkins (or Hudson) job for it.

P.S.: I think, the question won't be so important when we'll use Jenkins, because we can make two jobs running one after another. But even though we might not need it, I'm still curious if it's possible.

Comment: I don't know anything about protractor, but is it not possible to just make a batch-script that first runs protractor with one config, then with the other ?

Comment: Sure. But I'd like to know if there is such an option in protractor itself.

Comment: I don't think there is such an option inbuilt in protractor. You probably need to hack one yourself.